# Could not run an R Script from command prompt in Windows

Tags: r, command-prompt

I could not run my R Script from command prompt . Even if I have updated the path in environment variables.
It is displaying the following error message:

'rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

What could be the issue behind this?

Comment: If the directory containing `Rscript.exe` were on your path you would not be getting this message. You can inspect your path by running `echo %PATH%` from a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks this solution worked for me.

Comment: Hi, could you please be a bit more specific on "if the directory containing the .exe were on the path"?